# Basic CSS width calculation confuse

Tags: css

All:

I wonder if I set father DIV width:auto and set Child div width:100%, then how browser decides the width of those DIVs

```
<div class="menuframe" style="position: fixed; width:auto; height:auto;">
    <div class="menuitem style="width:100%; height:auto;">item1</div>
    <div class="menuitem style="width:100%; height:auto;">item22</div>
    <div class="menuitem style="width:100%; height:auto;">item333</div>
    <div class="menuitem style="width:100%; height:auto;">item4444</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Block level elements will expand to 100% width of their parent by default.

Comment: @Shikkediel Thanks, I guess my question should be more like: How do I know the width the browser assign to menuframe?

Comment: I hadn't noticed yet the parent had fixed position. This makes it a special case - it will not automatically get assigned full width but will only be as wide as the content is. *Absolutely positioned elements will shrink-wrap to fit their contents unless you specify their dimensions.* http://tinyurl.com/p8kcqvf

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="menuframe" style="background-color: red; position: fixed; width:auto; height:auto;">
    <div class="menuitem" style="background-color: blue; width:100%; height:auto;">item1</div>
    <div class="menuitem" style="background-color: black; width:100%; height:auto;">item22</div>
    <div class="menuitem" style="background-color: green; width:100%; height:auto;">item333</div>
    <div class="menuitem style="width:100%; height:auto;">item4444</div>
</div>
```

As you can see it will get the largest div width.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my question should be more like: How do I know the width the browser assign to menuframe? Because it seems the parent and children depend on each other.

Answer (score 0):

The menuitem divs should always be 100% width of the menuframe. How wide menuframe is depends on what CSS you set for it.

Comment: I actually did not set any width to it, just put that html in body tag, I kinda wondering how browser assign this width?

Comment: The only simple, if rather unhelpful answer, is probably "however it can". Any element will be positioned and sized according to the render engine of the browser, which hopefully results in a consistent and expected result. We know from decades of pain that this isn't always what we get because browsers may do different things to each other or unexpected things! Check out http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#rendering but you will notice it starts out "User agents are not required to present HTML documents in any particular way".